# Define a method `sum_to_n?`

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the code below. Method `sum_to_n?` takes an array `arr` of integers and an integer `n` as arguments and returns `true` if any two elements in `arr` sum to `n`. It should return `true` for empty `arr` with zero `n`, but keeps returning `false`.

```
def sum_to_n?(arr, n)
  hash = Hash.new(0)
  arr.each do |val|
    if hash.key? val
      return true
    else
      hash[n-val] = val
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming your `return false` is meant to be inside the `def`, right? Also, there's really no reason to give the hash a default of `0`.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for all your responses.

Comment: What should sum_to_n?([1], 1) return?  There is no pair that equals 1 but if sum_to_n?([], 0) returns true seems like sum_to_n?([1], 1) should too

Answer (score 7):

shorter version:

```
def sum_to_n?(arr, n)
  (arr.empty? && n.zero?) || arr.permutation(2).any? { |a, b| a + b == n }
end
```

Comment: While let us also note, that @spickermann's algorithm runs in `O(n²)`, while with a bit more effort, the problem can be solved in `O(n)`, iianm.

Comment: Great Answer !! Really appreciate it. When I test : 

puts sum_to_n?([],1)

It should return false for the empty array with nonzero argument. :(

Comment: Fixed the answer to return `false` for empty `arr` with nonzero `n`. About the complexity: I prefer readability of code as long as slower run time is not a problem. Depends on how big your problem is.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! Just for reference, in the original code you posted and this last one, what did you change ? Cant find the difference.

Comment: @EricArambula : I added `&& n.zero?` that handles empty array with zero `n`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is (almost) correct, but your expectation is wrong. Your code returns `true` when there are two (or one) element that adds up to `n`. If you pass an empty array, then there will not be any element(s) that add up to `n` (because there is no element in the array in the first place). Hence, you get `false`.

If you want it to return `true` for an empty array, then that would be an exceptional behavior  that does not follow logically. You will have to put a condition such as

```
return true if arr.empty?
```

in your code.

Comment: This one answers `What am I doing wrong ?`, that is the question. @spickermann shows a better overall way to achieve what the OP wants, but this is the "correct answer".