# How to create a nested loop with Ruby the "Right Way!"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops

I'm in the process of learning Ruby, taking a Berkeley's MOOC, and, in some of these MOOC's homework we have an exercise that says:

> Define a method sum_to_n? which takes an array of integers and an
>   additional integer, n, as arguments and returns true if any two
>   elements in the array of integers sum to n. An empty array should sum
>   to zero by definition.

I already created two methods that can do the job, but I'm not comfortable with any of them because I think they are not written in the Ruby Way. I hope some of you can help me to learn which would be the right way!

The first method I made uses the `each` method for both iterations, but what I don't like about this method is that every number is summed with every other number, even with the same number, doing something like this:

```
arr[1, 2, 3, 4] => 1+1, 1+2, 1+3, 1+4, 2+1, 2+2, 2+3, 2+4, 3+1, 3+2... 4+3, 4+4
```

As you can see, there's a lot of repeated sums, and I don't want that.

This is the code:

```
def sum_to_n?(arr, n)
  arr.each {|x| arr.each {|y| return true if x + y == n && x != y}}
  return true if n == 0 && arr.length == 0
  return false
end
```

With the other method I got what I wanted, just a few sums without repeating any of them or even summing the same numbers, but it looks HORRIBLE, and I'm pretty sure someone would love to kill me for doing it this way, but the method does a great job as you can see:

```
arr[1, 2, 3, 4] => 1+2, 1+3, 1+4, 2+3, 2+4, 3+4
```

This is the code:

```
def sum_to_n?(arr, n)
  for i in 0..arr.length - 1
    k = i + 1
    for k in k..arr.length - 1
      sum = arr[i] + arr[k]
      if sum == n
        return true
      end
    end
  end
  return true if n == 0 && arr.length == 0
  return false
end
```

Well, I hope you guys have fun doing a better and prettier method as I did trying.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Normally, I would be weary of using `for` ever in Ruby, but in this case, it's acceptable as second method will have less iterations than using `each`.

Comment: While Ruby has `for`, we tend to ignore it because there are some side-effects, such as it leaving its intermediate variable hanging around to clutter the variable space, and it forcing us to iterate over the container using calculated indexes, rather than allowing `each` to pass in each item individually. Indexes missing the first or last element, or falling off the end, are common bugs in all languages, and `each` helps avoid that. So, while it *might* seem like a stylistic choice, it's really a defensive programming choice. And, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Appartently, Berkeley's "Massive Open Online Courses" are generating massive interest in SO =)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd write it like this:

```
def sum_to_n?(arr, n)
  return true if arr.empty? && n.zero?
  arr.combination(2).any? {|a, b| a + b == n }
end
```

That seems to be a pretty Rubyish solution.

Comment: Damn. I'm a Rubyist and even I'm surprised at how Rubyish that solution was. Well done.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant.

Comment: You is a smart guy, I have no doubts about that. Can you Enlighten us with a generic answer for this question? Your works because a method that does what the OP wants exists, but what if you have a generic nested loops? Or you should not have any, and if you have you are doing it wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I came across this on [CodeWars](http://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-eq-n/). The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19371550/3189203) sure does look very Rubyish, but that is at the cost of performance. Calling `arr.combination(2)` results in a lot of combinations, it'd be simpler to go over the array element by element and search whether the 'complement' `sum - element` exists. Here's how that'd look like -

```
def sum_to_n?(arr, n)
  (arr.empty? and n.zero?) or arr.any? { |x| arr.include?(n - x) }
end
```

Comment: Why do you need the first parenthetical expression? Empty arrays won't cause `any?` or `include?` to throw errors. It's a good answer, I just think it could be a little more concise.

Comment: @mark-thomas - "An empty array should sum to zero by definition" is what the question says - If it weren't for the first expression, `sum_to_n?([], 0) would return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Beside @jorg-w-mittag's answer. I found another solution using 'permutation'.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19351660/66493

```
def sum_to_n?(arr, n)
  (arr.empty? && n.zero?) || arr.permutation(2).any? { |a, b| a + b == n }
end
```

I didn't know about permutation before.
Still like @jorg-w-mittag answer because its more readable.

Comment: `permutation` considers order important. This will result in redundant sums, e.g. `a + b` and `b + a`. Therefore `combination` is the better choice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This one will do it in `O(n.log(n))` rather than `O(n²)`:

```
a = 1, 2, 3, 4

class Array
  def sum_to? n
    unless empty?
      false.tap {
        i, j, sorted = 0, size - 1, sort
        loop do
          break if i == j
          a, b = sorted[i], sorted[j]
          sum = a + b
          return a, b if sum == n
          sum < n ? i += 1 : j -= 1
        end
      }
    end
  end
end

a.sum_to? 7 #=> [3, 4]
```

Comment: It's not O(n) if it uses `Array#sort`.

Comment: You'r right, including `Array#sort`, it's (probably) `O(n.log(n))`, edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a thought that the beginning of any answer to this question should probably start with pruning the array for superfluous data:

Can't use this:

```
  arr.select! { |e| e <= n } # may be negative values
```

But this might help:

```
  arr.sort!
  while arr[0] + arr[-1] > n # while smallest and largest value > n
    arr.delete_at(-1) # delete largest vaue
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I like rohitpaulk's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30012616/8706387) but it fails when n doubles x. We should remove x from the array before sending `include? n - x`.

```rb
def sum_to_n?(arr, n)
  return true if arr.empty? && n.zero?
  arr.any? { |x| arr.tap { arr.delete_at arr.index x }.include? n - x }
end
```

Lam Phan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69520639/8706387) using a hash is the best

Answer (score 0):

i wonder why no answers here using `hash` ?

```rb
def sum_to_n?(arr, n)
  return true if arr.empty? && n.zero?

  h = {}
  arr.any? { |x| complement = h[n-x]; h[x] = true; complement }
end

puts sum_to_n?([1,2,3,4,5,7], 6) # true
puts sum_to_n?([6,2,3,5,7,9], 6) # false
puts sum_to_n?([3,4,5,3], 6) # true
puts sum_to_n?([3,4,5,7], 6) # false
puts sum_to_n?([], 6) # false
puts sum_to_n?([], 0) # true
```